# Persistent/Customer/Form/Register not getting overridden Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, persistent

I am trying to override the block Mage_Customer_Form_Register

I have written this in my config.xml

```
<blocks>
        <registration>
            <class>Neo_Registration_Block</class>
        </registration>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <form_register>Neo_Registration_Block_Form_Register</form_register>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
    </blocks>
```

And this is not working as the methods I wrote in my local overriden block are not getting called.

And as the register.phtml is written in Persistent module,

So now how I can override this block ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

**config.xml file as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyWeb_Brand>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyWeb_Brand>
    </modules>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <MyWeb_Brand_Route>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyWeb_Brand</module>
                    <frontName>brand</frontName>
                </args>
            </MyWeb_Brand_Route>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <brand>
                <class>MyWeb_Brand_Block</class>
            </brand>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <form_register>MyWeb_Brand_Block_Form_Register</form_register>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your block file Register.php file at **app/code/MyWeb/Brand/Block/Form/Register.php**

add below code to it

```
<?php

class MyWeb_Brand_Block_Form_Register extends Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register
{
}
```

Note: Change module name as per your module

Comment: can you tell me whats the difference between your edit and my edit?  https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/95879      yours:    https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/102887/revisions    why you rejected?

Comment: Why are you rejecting my suggestions continuously?